# custom stereo rig

Tags: stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We are building a custom stereo rig. We are using prosilica camera and using their syncin1 trigger mechanism with an external trigger board. I saw that the ros prosilica drivers had options for it but has it been tested? Also the second thing is how much sync problems do you think we will have? Any one has done something similar?

Thanks,

Benzun

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55982/custom-stereo-rig/) by [Benny](https://answers.ros.org/users/2216/benny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 132 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Benzun,

We have build a stereo rig composed of two Allied Prosilica GC655C cameras. We have tested 2 configurations:

- Sending a periodic trigger from an external board to the SyncIn1 pins of both cameras.
- Sending a soft trigger to one of the cameras which is forwarded to the SyncIn1 pin of the second camera through the SyncOut1 pin of the first one. See vendors' technical manual about the connection scheme.

The drawback that we found with the first configuration is that even if the cameras are synchronized, when operating at high rate there is no guarantee that when getting the latest images from each camera these correspond to the same trigger time. Nevertheless, I find this configuration valid if the image acquisition from software is ensured to be within two external triggers.

The latter configuration ensures image synchronization as cameras are operated in poll request and both start capturing at the same time. The parameters that we had to configure for the first camera were:

```
FrameStartTriggerMode: "software"
SyncOut1Mode: "Strobe1"
SyncOut1Invert: "On"
Strobe1ControlledDuration: "On"
Strobe1Delay: 0
Strobe1Duration: 1000
Strobe1Mode: "FrameTrigger"
```

and for the second camera:

```
FrameStartTriggerMode: "SyncIn1"
FrameStartTriggerEvent: "EdgeFalling"
```

---

Originally posted by [Jordi Pages](https://answers.ros.org/users/626/jordi-pages/) with karma: 245 on 2013-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1